# Two data streams in one flink job

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have two infinite kafka data streams in one flink job, like this:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataStream kafka1 = ...
DataStream kafka2 = ...

kafka1.process();
kafka2.process();

environment.execute();
```

Does the process of the two streams are parallel or in sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only use one environment, the task will run in parallel.